# Why is $2f(x)$ in the same function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

My SAT Math essentials book says:
$$f(x) = 8x - 2$$
becomes
$$f(3) = 8(3) - 2f(3) = 24 - 2 = 22$$
So, when $x = 3$, the value of the function is $22$.

Why did the author insert $2f(3)$ if *that line* equals $44$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. What your book says reads better if a semicolon is inserted between $2$ and $f(3)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Oh I see. It is a typo. Thanks. I do not know how I overlooked that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that $2f(3)=44$.  I think your book author meant “$f(3)=8(3)-2\color{red}; f(3)=24-2$,” which is correct.